# Last Column green in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

Trying to colour the last column of a table green.

I have a table which uses Bootstrap styles (it's ASP.Net) and wants the last column to be green. The table is longer than this but it's 'Group 5' in the headers and the last value in each tr.

```css
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-light border-primary">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Group1</th>
                <th scope="col">Group2</th>
                <th scope="col">Group3</th>
                <th scope="col">Group4</th>
                <th scope="col">Group5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2022-03-14</th>
                <td>52900</td>
                <td>6530</td>
                <td>2957</td>
                <td>778</td>
                <td>15947</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2022-03-21</th>
                <td>52900</td>
                <td>6530</td>
                <td>2957</td>
                <td>778</td>
                <td>15947</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The final table will have several more rows but I always want the last column to be colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :last-of-type for this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

```
.table thead th:last-of-type,
.table tbody td:last-of-type {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I got sidetracked and pulled into P1 issue after this and forgot to come back! This worked thanks very much